# Unable to issue commands to a remote server when using IP address

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, rpc, pstools

I know this is going to sound crazy and I hope that I may just be missing something simple. I am trying to use psexec to restart IIS on a cluster of remote servers. The dept that actually uses the scripts only know the servers by IP address and not hostnames. For some reason 1 of the servers does not work when issuing the command by IP. Here is an example.

WORKS:

```
psexec \\hostname cmd
```

DOESNT WORK:

```
psexec \\ipAddress cmd
```

I know the ip is correct. I can verify with nslookup and I can RDP into the server via IP address. This server is a virtual and should be identical to every other server in the cluster. I have never seen anything where hostname works fine and ip fails... The routing seems to be fine too since I make it to the server. I am kinda at a loss here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the netlogon service was stopped on the server. Weird behavior considering everything worked via hostname.